# Do Adrenaline Skills have separate adrenaline bars?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I wanted to go for a hybrid Alchemy/Swordsmanship build this time around. The Witcher Wiki says:

> If talents are invested in more than one of these skills, the associated Adrenaline fueled abilities will be activated simultaneously.

Now The Witcher 2 has three different Adrenaline skills followed by three different adrenaline generation methods:

1. Heliotrope Sign, provided by Sense Magic - generates adrenaline when hit enemy with a Sign
2. Group Finishers, provided by Combat Acumen - generates adrenaline for each successful sword blow
3. Berserk Mode, provided by Mutant - generates adrenaline gradually, when poisoned by drinking potions and in combat

My question is: as the skills are triggered by the same keystroke (X by default), I understand that I activate both of them when I press it. However, do adrenaline generation contributes to the same Adrenaline Bar or do those skills have separate bars, each fueled exclusively by its own generation method?

Answer (score 3):

No, they don't.

Just one single bar. So all skills provide adrenaline to the same bar.
[image: Witcher 2 Wikia Adrenaline Bar]