# The witcher 2, how does adrenaline works?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm just wondering, what **adrenaline** is in *The Witcher 2*, and how am I supposed to use it?

I can't see any adrenaline bar or something like that, so I'm a bit confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adrenaline bar is activated once you learn your first ability which requires/uses adrenaline.

Also see in the Witcher wiki:
 [Adrenaline Rush](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Adrenaline_rush)

The three skill trees will give you different abilities which are activateable with <kbd>X</kbd> (in the case you play with a gamepad directional button up):

1. **Swordman skill tree:** Instant Multi Kill of 3 enemies
2. **Magic skill tree:** A field similar to Yrden
3. **Alchemy skill tree:** More attack and defences

This answer is also interesting and provides a screenshot of the adrenaline bar:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/178593